# Counter example for Random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables, examples-counterexamples

I read  the result that if $|X|$ is random variable then  $X$ need not be random variable.

So, I am looking for counter example.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take any non-measurable subset $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and define
$$
X(\omega)=\mathbf{1}_A(\omega)-\mathbf{1}_{A^c}(\omega),\quad\omega\in\mathbb{R},
$$
where $\mathbf{1}_A$ is the indicator function for the set $A$. Then $|X|=1$ is a random variable but $X$ isn't a random variable (why?).